# How to fix the OCaml compile error when using type annotations with functors?

Tags: ocaml, functor

I am new to OCaml and I am trying use functors. When I use the module type annotations with the functors, this results in a compile time error in my code.

When I remove the `: Printable` (from the `module FromToString` line) and the `: ToString` (from the `module IntToString` line) annotations, the following program compiles without error:

```
module type ToString =
sig
    type t
    val to_string: t -> string
end

module type Printable =
sig
    type t
    val print: t -> unit
end

module FromToString (S:ToString) : Printable  =
struct
    type t = S.t
    let print a = print_string ( S.to_string a) 
end

module IntToString : ToString =
struct
    type t = int
    let to_string = string_of_int
end

module PrintableInt = FromToString(IntToString)
let () = PrintableInt.print 3
```

However, when I add these annotations (as shown in the code) the compiler gives the following error:

```
File "Functor.ml", line 26, characters 28-29:
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
         PrintableInt.t = FromToString(IntToString).t
```

How can I use these annotations without causing a compile error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root issue is that your signature constraints make the resulting module far too opaque. When you constrain your functor result:

```
 module FromToString (S:ToString) : Printable = ...
```

you are making the type `t` an abstract type, which can only be consumed by the `to_string` function and never been produced. In other words, a module of type `Printable` is unusable by itself.

When starting with functor, it is very often useful to look at the module type inferred by the compiler for the resulting module.
In the `FromToString` case, this is:

```
module FromToString (S:ToString) : sig
  type t = S.t
  val print: t -> unit
end = ...
```

You can see that the inferred module type of the result

```
 sig
   type t = S.t
   val print: t -> unit
 end
```

that it is quite similar to `Printable` except that now the type `t` is equal to the type `t` of the argument module `S`.

Thus, it is possible to reuse `Printable` to write the full module type of the result by adding a type equality with a `with` constraint:

```
  module FromToString (S:ToString): Printable with type t = S.t = struct
    type t = S.t
    let print a = print_string ( S.to_string a) 
  end
```

The same issue appears for IntToString and can be fixed in a similar way:

```
module IntToString : ToString with type t = int =
struct
    type t = int
    let to_string = string_of_int
end
```

Then the compiler error is gone:

```
module PrintableInt = FromToString(IntToString)
let () = PrintableInt.print 3
```

Answer (score 0):

One has to make the type t public, using the `with` notation:

```
module type ToString =
sig
    type t
    val to_string: t -> string
end

module type Printable =
sig
    type t
    val print: t -> unit
end

module FromToString (S:ToString) : Printable with type t = S.t =
struct
    type t = S.t
    let print a = print_string ( S.to_string a) 
end

module IntToString : ToString with type t =int  =
struct
    type t = int
    let to_string = string_of_int
end

module PrintableInt = FromToString(IntToString)
let () = PrintableInt.print 3
```